# elasticsearch - add custom field to a specific index

Tags: elasticsearch

I hava the JSON for my index that looks like this:

```
{
"_index": "myindes",
"_type": "external",
"_id": "1",
"_source": {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "myName",
   "description": "myDescription",
   "source": "mySource",
   }
}
```

And i want to add a string field in `_source` named `topic`

How can i do

Answer (score 0):

You can update the index mapping as

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping/external' -d '
{
    "external" : {
        "properties" : {
            "id": {"type":"string"},
            "name": {"type":"string"},
            "description": {"type":"string"},
            "source": {"type":"string"},
            "topic":{"type":"string"}  //  <---new field
        }
    }
}'
```

Although the above step was not necessary but always good to control what you are indexing.

Now, you can index your documents with the new field and it will reflect in new updates. However, old indexed documents will still not contain this new field. You will have to reindex them.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, now how can i fix the changes; looking on kibana or doing a query does not show me the topic field